# PHP SDK: How do I capture the access token after user auths app?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, oauth-2.0, access-token, facebook-canvas

This is for a canvas app on the Facebook Platform using the new(est) Facebook PHP SDK.

We are using the PHP example from the Facebook tutorial (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) to trigger the OAuth dialog and get the test user to the redirect URL.

At the redirect URL, we use the PHP example from the Facebook signed request docs page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and our test users can successfully authorize the app.

However, after the test user auths the app, we are not able to capture the access token and its expiration. We can see it in the address bar appended to the redirect URL, but it does not show up in the $_REQUEST array. If we add {$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();} to the redirect URL page, it shows a value for the access token, but the value it shows is not the full token string that we see when we click on Show Token in the Test User Roles page (which we believe is the correct access token for the test user).

Here is an example of the redirect URL with an access token appended: 
http://karmakorn.com/karmakorn/alpha20/kk-fb-auth.php#access_token=126736467765%7C2.AQDavId8oL80P5t9.3600.1315522800.1-100002908746828%7CJICJwM1P_97tKmqkEO5pXDCf-7Y&expires_in=6008

Here is what var_dump shows for the $*REQUEST array for that same page: 
array(3) { ["*_qca"]=> string(26) "P0-709927483-1291994912966" ["__switchTo5x"]=> string(2) "30" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "euois02ead39ijumca7nffblh2" }

We have no idea why the $_REQUEST array varies from the values appended to the URL, and more importantly -- how to capture the access token and its expiration date.

Can someone show us a working example of how they capture this data after running the parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) function on the redirect page? Thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFO:

Here is the pertinent code from A) our test index page, and B) our test redirect page. If we use our text index page as the redirect url it gets stuck in an endless loop -- because the user is never identified.

A) Index Page

```
// Create kk-fb app instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => KKFB_ID,
    'secret' => KKFB_KY,
    'oauth' => true,
));

$app_id = KKFB_ID;
$secret = KKFB_KY;
$canvas_auth = 'http://karmakorn.com/karmakorn/alpha20/kk-fb-auth.php';

$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" 
                . "client_id=" . $app_id 
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_auth) 
                . "&response_type=token" 
                . "&scope=email,publish_stream";

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
}
```

B) Redirect Page

```
// Create kk-fb app instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => KKFB_ID,
    'secret' => KKFB_KY,
    'oauth' => true,
));

$app_id = KKFB_ID;
$secret = KKFB_KY;

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

echo "User: $user <br>";
echo "Access Token: $access_token <br>";
echo "Signed Request: $signed_request <br>";
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Here is what shows up as these echo results:

User: 0 
Access Token: 126736467765|*****SECRET*****
Signed Request: 
array(3) { ["_*qca"]=> string(26) "P0-709927483-1291994912966" ["*_switchTo5x"]=> string(2) "30" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "frugi545cdl15gjind1fnv6pq1" }

Interestingly, when the test user goes back to the index page the if condition is satisfied and we can get the correct access token:

Welcome User: 100002908746828
Access Token: 126736467765|2.AQBgcyzfu75IMCjw.3600.1315544400.1-100002908746828|m5IYEm976tJAkbTLdxHAhhgKmz8

Obviously, we are still missing something!? Also, we need to learn how to get the expiration time as a variable too so we can store both of these in our database.

Answer (score 13):

OK, let's try this again.

#### Server-side vs Client-side Authentication

You are exclusively using the PHP SDK, so you want to do server-side authentication, where the authentication code is sent to the server over HTTP via the URL. This will allow you to fetch an access token for the user on the first page load after auth (in your case, the redirect page). The auth_url you are currently constructing is setting `response_type=token`, which forces the redirect to use client-side auth mode and set the token in the URL fragment instead of in the query. You should remove that parameter completely. In fact, I highly recommend you just use the PHP SDK instead of constructing that URL yourself. See example below.

#### Application Access Tokens

The odd-looking access token 126736467765|**SECRET** is your application access token, which is composed of your app ID and secret key. The application access token is returned by `getAccessToken()` if no user access token is available (because some API calls require at least some sort of access token). This also means that you've revealed your secret key to the world via this blog post, so you should [reset your app secret](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/126736467765/summary) otherwise anyone will be able to make API calls on your behalf. I highly recommend you elide parts of your access tokens if you share them with others.

#### Token Expiration

The OAuth 2.0 flow and v3.1.1 of the PHP SDK don't make determining the expiration time of a token all that easy. I would suggest attempting to make the API call, and then [refreshing the token](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500) if the API call fails with an `OAuthException`. Tokens can be invalid even if they haven't expired, so this deals with more cases. However, if you still want to maintain the expiration date on your end, you might just want to extract it from the token itself. If you have an expiring token, then the expiration timestamp will be contained within that string. Here's a function I put together quickly to extract that:

```
function extractExpirationFromToken($access_token) {
    $segments = explode('|', $access_token);
    if(count($segments) < 2) { return 0; }

    $segments = explode('.', $segments[1]);
    if(count($segments) < 4) { return 0; }

    $expires = $segments[3];
    $dash_pos = strrpos($expires, '-');
    if($dash_pos !== false) {
        $expires = substr($expires, 0, $dash_pos);
    }
    return $expires;
}
```

#### New Index Page Code

```
// Create kk-fb app instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => KKFB_ID,
    'secret' => KKFB_KY,
));

$canvas_auth = 'http://karmakorn.com/karmakorn/alpha20/kk-fb-auth.php';

$auth_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email,publish_stream',
    'redirect_uri' => $canvas_auth, // you could just redirect back to this index page though
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (empty($user)) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $user);
}
```

#### Redirect Page

I don't think you need this page at all. You could just redirect the user back to your original index page.

```
// Create kk-fb app instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => KKFB_ID,
    'secret' => KKFB_KY,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
// also copy the function definition given earlier
$expiration = extractExpirationFromToken($access_token);

echo "User: $user <br>";
echo "Access Token: $access_token <br>";
echo "Expiration: $expiration <br>";
echo "Request: <br>";
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: PC, thanks for the follow-up with such thorough code examples. Very generous of you! Makes me wonder why the Facebook docs confuse us with the signed_request code examples? Anyway, your example did enable me to collapse this into a single page without the endless looping. Using the original index page took my test user out of the browser though. If I use apps.facebook.com instead, it keeps me in the browser. However, the address bar url is full of state info which can detract from the user experience. If we use the 2-page process instead, we get a clean url. So we may stick with that.

Comment: PC, your expertise & generosity are very helpful. I would welcome an invitation from you to connect on LinkedIn. Bill

Answer (score 2):

You can use the facebook build in method getAccessToken() for example;

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

This will give you the access token to your variable, now if you are getting it empty, remember to first check if the fuid is being properly catch, if it isn't you might need to review your settings be sure your "App Domain" is set this part is very important after setting it correctly you need to reset your app secret, then set your new values in your auth code. Hope this help, let me know :)

pd. Also remember to keep the scope of your variables visible in your whole php file or class.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The `access_token` in your pasted URL is not part of the query string, but instead contained in the URL fragment (after the #). URL fragments are not sent to the web server, and are readable only by client-side code like Javascript. Therefore the PHP SDK only sees http://karmakorn.com/karmakorn/alpha20/kk-fb-auth.php, which is why `$_REQUEST` does not contain an `access_token` key.

#### Questions / Notes

1. What are you using for your redirect_uri? I think you want to be using something like http://apps.facebook.com/your_canvas_url/
2. You shouldn't need to call `parse_signed_request` yourself or copy any code from the signed request page. The PHP SDK will do that for you. Just call:

   ```
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => '…',
       'secret' => '…',
   ));
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
   ```

#### Possible solutions

1. Also use the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). You can start by adding its `<script>` tag in your destination page (kk-fb-auth.php) (see [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for full details; don't forget to set `oauth: true`). The JS SDK should set a cookie (named fbsr_126736467765) which the PHP SDK will be able to read via `$_REQUEST` or `$_COOKIE` on subsequent page loads.

Comment: PC, thanks for the helpful distinction between the query string and url fragments (which we'll have to learn more about). I've added some more detail to our question. We'd really like to solve this entirely with PHP, since our app is data-intensive and the Facebook JavaScript SDK shows a bit too much latency for our purposes -- we need to populate our app pages with a lot of data from our database after we get the Facebook ID for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with PHP, you can get the user's access token with a separate call to the Graph API at your redirect_uri. For this you need to change the response_type of your $auth_url in your index page to "code" or "code token".

Then, at your redirect page, Facebook will add a "code" parameter in the querystring. This API call will return you the full access_token and expiration time:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
    redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
    client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
    code=$_REQUEST['code']
```

For more information you can refer to the [docs on authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: Gig, in order to do this we need to get a valid Facebook uid for the test user. The problem is that our redirect page keeps getting a uid of 0 after the test user authorizes the app. We wonder if this is due to some kind of latency problem with the Facebook servers? Until we can succeed in receiving a valid uid on our redirect page, it seems that alternative ways of getting the access token are moot. Maybe we have to "muscle" through the latency problem by redirecting   to yet another page to get the uid? As noted above, returning to the index page does get a valid uid for the test user.

Comment: Bill, the reason you're getting uid=0 is because as Gigablah suggests the `response_type=token` parameter is actually preventing the server from receiving the data it needs. That approach only works with the JS SDK. When using PHP you need to first receive the auth code then fetch the access token yourself. See [my latest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354978/php-sdk-how-do-i-capture-the-access-token-after-user-auths-app/7367511#7367511). I think JS is setting a cookie from the URL fragment on page load, which is why you only see the user logged in on subsequent page requests.