# facebook access_tokens in php and js diffeerent?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going crazy here,

i dont understand how facebook handles the token thing. I use php sdk for web login. This works, i can get with

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

the data from user etc.

But after a short time i do get the ***** fb error:

```
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

even though the user is still logged in. When i disconnect and login with facebook again, i do not get a new token (i think because the cookie is still active?)

When i delete all cookies it works for a while.

**BUT** when i check back with JS SDK

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){FB.api('/me', function(response) {});});
```

I always have an active access_token and within it i can call the api, but only within...

Why i cannot use the same token in php and js or why are they different?????

Please help me.

**EDIT**

To explain it better. In php the access_token changes from e.g. 'CDAtEg' etc. to '148234' etc. (dont know why). if i do the api request in php i got the OAuthException but in js SDK the old Token 'CDAtEg' is still active and i got the user_data till the token exprires.

Why i cannot use the same token in php again and why it is deleted? I do not find the reason for that.

**EDIT 2**

Thank you for your ideas so far. I found out two things now. First, when i save the token i get from JS SDK and use it with

```
$facebook->setAccessToken()
```

it seems to work so far. Second, as phwd posted below the user_access token i got from php is deleted after 2,3 minutes. How can i found the origin of this problem?

Comment: After a short time ... they should last for two hours! Did you check the expiry when you received the token?

Comment: I do both api calls the same time and in php i get an token error in js not, even though i use the same token. So it is not expired.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tokens expire because they are the same user token.

In the PHP SDK, if the token expires or gets thrown out for some error, the PHP SDK will set the default token to the application token

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L389

```
  /**
   * Determines the access token that should be used for API calls.
   * The first time this is called, $this->accessToken is set equal
   * to either a valid user access token, or it's set to the application
   * access token if a valid user access token wasn't available.  Subsequent
   * calls return whatever the first call returned.
   *
   * @return string The access token
   */
  public function getAccessToken() {
    if ($this->accessToken !== null) {
      // we've done this already and cached it.  Just return.
      return $this->accessToken;
    }

    // first establish access token to be the application
    // access token, in case we navigate to the /oauth/access_token
    // endpoint, where SOME access token is required.
    $this->setAccessToken($this->getApplicationAccessToken());
    $user_access_token = $this->getUserAccessToken();
    if ($user_access_token) {
      $this->setAccessToken($user_access_token);
    }

    return $this->accessToken;
  }
```

Thus you must introduce login handling in PHP to ensure no calls are taken unless a valid user access token is supplied.

In JS SDK, most setups unless you explicitly set it otherwise will push the user through login after token expiry.

As you describe it seems as though an error is pushing the PHP SDK to use the default application token.

You can even sure that the user access token being used in the JS SDK will work in the PHP SDK *if it is indeed still active*, by setting it

```
$facebook->setAccessToken('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_IN_JS_SDK');
```

Once this works then the error elsewhere in your code (which you have not supplied).

Comment: Ah thank you now i am one step foreward. when i set the token in php  i get 'Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.' ['code'] => 190 ['error_subcode'] => 467. But the user does not logged out, only i tested when a user rejects the publish_actions permission. Maybe this is the reason i lost the session and token?

Answer (score 0):

After some time-interval access token gets expired. Facebook gives new access token for every session. Access token is not always same for each user and each session.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, but i dont understand what do you mean, why i get the message in php but not in js and how i can get a token in php when its not there.

Comment: Also check https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: Hm this is very old, but still uptodate? seems not so.

Comment: @RuvenJR.Maerson I mean that after every 2 hour you have to acquire new access token.

Answer (score 0):

> BUT when i check back with facebook SDK

This is happens because `FB.api` check is your `access_token` valid and if not valid update it.

In php you need to do this manually. More with code examples  [PHP SDK: How do I capture the access token after user auths app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354978/php-sdk-how-do-i-capture-the-access-token-after-user-auths-app)

Comment: @RuvenJR.Maerson I think you can not trust any any tokens which js can change.

Comment: but this is the token i get directly from facebook response and it is the same as i get with getAcesstoken() (at begin when its set) in php. thats why i still not understand what is the difference between both at this point.

Comment: @RuvenJR.Maerson hard to say without full code example. In theory it has to be identical but this is fb, so we can't be sure :)