# How to get parameter from the url?

Tags: php

I have to get value of `access_token` from a URL, like:

```
localhost/facebook/#access_token=xyz
```

`$_GET['access_token']` doesn't work. How can I get the value of `access_token`?

Comment: You get it with JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: because you have `/#` in the url and rest url it not getting with `$_GET[]`

Comment: How to get the value from javascript ? Please some hints.

Comment: is your response_type set to token? if so try code instead

Comment: If you're using the FB JavaScript API, this should all be transparent to you.

Comment: @NAB: a first hint: try google first

Comment: why not use FB's own `getAccessToken()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SDK: How do I capture the access token after user auths app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354978/php-sdk-how-do-i-capture-the-access-token-after-user-auths-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the hash part of the URL isn't sent to PHP, so can't be accessed via PHP. Javascript can access it, and can then pass it onto PHP.

There is a guide [here](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/) showing how.

Answer (score 1):

Use getAccessToken

```
$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $facebook->getAccessToken();
if(!$user){
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo '<a href="$loginUrl">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```

Clicking login with take you to fb, you login/accept whatever, then it redirects you back to your page and you get your access token.

Comment: Actually I need token.When I add token its return # .But response type is only code it works.

Comment: You can still get the token from using code. It just passes it through and you use `$_GET['code']`

Comment: I didn't find any method to get access token form code. Please any suggestion?

Comment: $facebook->getAccessToken(); get only an active access token. but i need accessToken from code. In my case redirect url in different . so no any cookies is there

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the login url?